# querying list within a list using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to learn linq, but struggling with some concepts.  How would I transform this double foreach loop into a linq query please?

```
foreach (var l1 in list1)
{
    foreach (var l2 in list2)
    {
       if (l1 == l2)
       {
          list1.Remove(l1);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: You wouldn't, because LINQ is about *querying*, not acting. Queries do not (should not) *modify* sequences. At best, you'd write a query that identifies the elements to be removed; then remove them in a second, separate step. Or derive a new sequence (with only a subset of the original elements) from the original sequences.

Comment: You shouldn't be mutating a list you are iterating over in the first place.

Comment: By the way: Note that your title is inaccurate. You do not have a list within a list; that would only be the case if you had a `List<List<T>>`. What you *do* have is a loop within a loop (both acting on a list and a list).

Answer (score 7):

```
var list3 = list1.Except(list2);
```

LINQ does not mutate lists.

Comment: As long as nothing else holds a reference to `list1` and expects it to be updated...

Comment: I'm always amazed how simply some tasks can be done if only you know how.  Anyway I'm getting there slowly. thanks!

Comment: @user3611219 If you spent some time looking through what all of the LINQ operators are and what each of them do (when trying to learn LINQ) you wouldn't be so surprised when one of them does *exactly* what you're trying to do.  That should be step 1 of learning LINQ.

Answer (score 3):

If `list1` is declared as a `List<T>`, then you can do this:

```
list1.RemoveAll(list2.Contains);
```

You might find that a little difficult to read. The above is essentially equivalent to:

```
list1.RemoveAll(item1 => list2.Contains(item1));
```

Note that this solution is not based on LINQ. However, if `list2`'s type does not have a `Contains` method, then LINQ can help you out with its `.Contains` extension method; add a `using System.Linq;` directive to your code in that case.)

<sub>**P.S.:** Please make sure that you have read and understood [my above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28368672/querying-list-within-a-list-using-linq#comment45078231_28368672): LINQ's purpose is querying for data, not modifying it.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

There is number of ways to do it, one example is to use `Intersect`:

```
var inBothLists = list1.Intersect(list2);

inBothLists.ToList().ForEach(i => list1.Remove(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

Linq is for *querying*, not *updating*, but you could query for the items that need to be removed and then remove them in a loop:

```
var itemsToRemove = list1.Where(l2.Contains(l1));
foreach(var item in itemsToRemove)
{
    list1.Remove(item)
}
```